# How to shuffle only row index in numpy arrays?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have two numpy arrays.I want to shuffle only their row index simultaneously. Although I equalize their row index then when i shuffle a why it doesn't automatically shuffled b

```
 a = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
 b = np.arange(10).reshape(10,1)
 a.shape[0]==b.shape[0]
 np.random.shuffle(a)
 print a
 print b
```

Comment: isn't `a.shape[0]==b.shape[0]` a useless statement? The boolean result is just lost, or is this from a REPL session?

Comment: What?  Why do you expect shuffling a to shuffle b?

Comment: While the functionality implied in `a.shape[0]==b.shape[0]` would be nice to have (basically marrying two arrays to be in the same order), it is not a normal function of a `numpy` array and would need a whole new class to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense, what you want to do can be down like below:

```
a = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
b = np.arange(10).reshape(10,1)
p = np.random.permutation(a.shape[0])
a = a[p]
b = b[p]
print a
print b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't marry two `numpy` arrays that way, to force them to stay in the same order.  What you can do is save the order in a separate array and then sort both of them by it.

```
a = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
b = np.arange(10).reshape(10,1)
i = np.random.shuffle(np.arange(a.size[0]))
print a[i]
print b[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.random.permutation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
b = np.arange(10).reshape(10,1)
perm = np.random.permutation(a.shape[0])
print(a[perm, :])
print(b[perm, :])
```

While [`numpy.random.shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) sorts the array in-place, in the last two lines of my code there is only a so called `view` of the arrays `a` and `b` created. If you check `a` and `b` afterwards, they are still the same. So if you want to use the shuffled version you should use something like `a = a[perm, :]` or `c = (a[perm, :]).copy()`.